# Spark S3 complete multipart upload error

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

I'm using Apache Spark for data processing and I occasionally see the following errors in logs when uploading to S3:

AmazonClientException: Unable to complete an encrypted multipart upload without being told which part was the last

Since spark does have retries on task failures, most of the time this is OK. However, I've run into issues when the retries exhaust causing the job to fail. Is there a better way to handle such errors besides retries ?

Thanks

Comment: can you pls add more info about exception/error ?

Answer (score 0):

That's interesting. Not seen that message, and I am currently co-ordinating most of the S3A Hadoop client dev.

Is this on Amazon EMR, or an official, self-contained ASF release?

If the former, you are on your own with the forums and any ASF support contract.

If the latter: file a JIRA on issues.apache.org under the HADOOP project (hadoop common), listing component fs/s3, declaring the exact version of the hadoop JARs on your spark CP, and including the full stack trace.